# Selecting rows in Pandas using multiple intervals (pd.Interval range objects)

Tags: python, pandas, etl

I need to use pd.Interval to select records across multiple bin ranges.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_col': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]})
df['my_col_bin'] = pd.cut(x=df['my_col'], bins=[0, 3, 6, 9, 12], right=False, include_lowest=True)
```

```
    my_col  my_col_bin
0   1   [0, 3)
1   2   [0, 3)
2   3   [3, 6)
3   4   [3, 6)
4   5   [3, 6)
5   6   [6, 9)
6   7   [6, 9)
7   8   [6, 9)
8   9   [9, 12)
9   10  [9, 12)
10  11  [9, 12)
```

For example, I would like to select all records that fall into range [3, 12). I would like to get the following output using single pd.Interval range, without specifying condition for each interval individually:

```
2   3   [3, 6)
3   4   [3, 6)
4   5   [3, 6)
5   6   [6, 9)
6   7   [6, 9)
7   8   [6, 9)
8   9   [9, 12)
9   10  [9, 12)
10  11  [9, 12)
```

I tried the following, which didn't work.

```
df[df['my_col_bin'] == pd.Interval(3, 12, closed='left')]
```

The following selection works on a single interval, but it appears that pd.Interval doesn't support multiple ranges.

```
df[df['my_col_bin'] == pd.Interval(3, 6, closed='left')]
```

Is it possible to select range across the bins without explicitly specifying each interval condition? Is there a succinct way to perform the selection without filtering for each interval individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [`Interval.overlaps`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.overlaps.html)

It does require an `apply`, but it turns out to be rather fast even for a large DataFrame. (Takes about 50 ms for 1 Million rows on my machine)

```
m = df['my_col_bin'].apply(lambda x: x.overlaps(pd.Interval(3, 12, closed='left')))

df[m]
    my_col my_col_bin
2        3     [3, 6)
3        4     [3, 6)
4        5     [3, 6)
5        6     [6, 9)
6        7     [6, 9)
7        8     [6, 9)
8        9    [9, 12)
9       10    [9, 12)
10      11    [9, 12)
```

Comment: How can I use it using filter instead of apply?

Comment: @verkter what do you mean to filter? I use it to create a mask that then filters to the rows you want. You can do it in one line `df[df['my_col_bin'].apply(lambda x: ...)]` but I split it out to make it a bit clearer .

Comment: Is there a cleaner way of selecting, or apply is necessary?

Comment: @verkter with Intervals no you typically need to use the apply. I mean you could represent the bounds as numpy arrays but at that point you'll likely need to pay the price to get the bounds anyway. I'm often surprised with the performance of apply with intervals. It turns out `apply` with Interval objects is on the fast side. Even with 100 Million rows the apply only takes about 1s, so it's not horrible.

Comment: For instance, the alterntive with `pd.arrays.IntervalArray(df['my_col_bin']).overlaps(pd.Interval(3, 12, closed='left'))` to create the mask is much slower`. The loop is probably hidden somewhere in the source code.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is not clean to this code in your view? @verkter

Answer (score 3):

What about selecting this way ?

```
df[(df['my_col'] >= 3) & (df['my_col'] < 12)]
```

Comment: I need to be able to select using the pd.Interval This is just a toy example

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is it possible to select range across the bins without explicitly specifying each interval condition? Is there a succinct way to perform the selection without filtering for each interval individually?

In general, the answer is:  **No**.

“In general” means that there are neither relations between individual intervals in your column (in your example they are) — nor the relation between the “target” interval (`[3, 12)`) and intervals in your column (in your example it is, too).

(See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783832/7023590) to your question which exploits such relations in your example.)

---

**Why?**

Pandas interval *is not a mathematical interval* (in the sense as a continuous set of real numbers).

Pandas interval is simply an ordered quadruplet of its properties `(.left, .right, .closed_left, .closed_right)`.

For example, your interval `[3, 12)` is nothing more than quadruplet `(3, 12, True, False)`.

---

**What consequences follow from it?**

It means that *there are no set operations / relation*s as *union, intersection, difference* or *subset.* And the last is exactly what you would need.

---

**How may I see that intervals are nothing more than mentioned quadruplets?**

From the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/_libs/interval.pyx), or — indirectly — from the provided method and properties of the class `Interval`. All of them are in a very simply manner derived from mentioned quadruplets:

> ```
> closed_left
> closed_right
> is_empty
> left
> length
> mid
> open_left
> open_right
> overlaps()
> right
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I exploit tight relations between intervals in your column `my_col_bin` and your target interval `[3, 12)`, which simply encompases 3 of that column's intervals.

(See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783540/7023590) to your question which is about the general case.)

```
In[1]: intervals = {interval for interval in df.my_col_bin 
                       if interval.left >= 3 and interval.right <= 12}
In[2]: intervals
```

> ```
> {Interval(3, 6, closed='left'),
>  Interval(6, 9, closed='left'),
>  Interval(9, 12, closed='left')}
> ```

or

```
In[1]: intervals = [pd.Interval(i, i + 3, closed="left") for i in range(3, 10, 3)]
In[2]: intervals
```

> ```
> [Interval(3, 6, closed='left'),
>  Interval(6, 9, closed='left'),
>  Interval(9, 12, closed='left')]
> ```

```
In[3]: df[df.my_col_bin.isin(intervals)]
```

> ```
>     my_col my_col_bin
> 2        3     [3, 6)
> 3        4     [3, 6)
> 4        5     [3, 6)
> 5        6     [6, 9)
> 6        7     [6, 9)
> 7        8     [6, 9)
> 8        9    [9, 12)
> 9       10    [9, 12)
> 10      11    [9, 12)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# transform in IntervalArray

df['my_col_bin']=pd.arrays.IntervalArray(df['my_col_bin'])

# # simply filter based in pd.Interval

df[df['my_col_bin'].array.overlaps(pd.Interval(3, 12, 
 closed='left'))]
```